# Overriding last file, when parsing excel file in multiple files (C# windows form)

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have a task to programatically parse an given excel file, to multiple excel files in a given location. Every file have an id column, and i have to parse it by id (for example if i have input 10, id's 0-9 go to first file, 10-19 go to the second one etc, until the end is reached). The problem is that at the last file, the content is overriden. As a test case, i have 1 file with IDs from 1 to 50 (including). This should have the output 6 files (0 for 1-9, 1 for 10-19, 2 for 20-29, 3 for 30-39, 4 for 4-49, and 5 for 50 only). My problem is that in file 4, the info is overridden , and it is the content for file 5 (the 50 item). I attached the source code below:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Excel_Splitter
{
    public partial class FormSpl : Form
    {

        string filePath = string.Empty, folderPath = string.Empty;

        public FormSpl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormSpl_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        }

        private void buttonSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filePath = file.FileName;
                labelPath.Text = filePath;
            }

        }


        private void buttonDestination_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = selectFolder.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectFolder.SelectedPath))
            {
                folderPath = selectFolder.SelectedPath;
                labelDestinationFolder.Text = folderPath;
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBoxValue.Text, "[^0-9]"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
                textBoxValue.Text = textBoxValue.Text.Remove(textBoxValue.Text.Length - 1);
            }
        }

        private void buttonParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxValue.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please write number of parse");
                return;
            }
            int parseNumber = int.Parse(textBoxValue.Text);
            string message = string.Empty;
            if (filePath.Equals(string.Empty))
                message += "Please select a file first!";
            if (filePath.Equals(string.Empty))
                message += "\nPlease select first where to save the files!";


            if (!message.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(message);
                return;
            }
            int columnID = 0;

            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;


            //search the ID column
            for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(xlRange.Cells[1, col].Value2) == "ID")
                {
                    columnID = col;
                    MessageBox.Show("column is " + columnID);
                    break;
                }

            }

            Excel.Workbook newOne;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            newOne = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)newOne.Worksheets.get_Item(1);


            //in thhe first line
            for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, col] = xlRange.Cells[1, col].Value;
            }


            int firstNumber = 0, rowsCurrent = 1;
            for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
            {

                //take the ID from current row   
                int currentID = Convert.ToInt32(xlRange.Cells[row, columnID].Value);
                if (currentID == 0)
                    break;
                if (currentID < parseNumber)
                    currentID = 0;

                //if is >value, take the first number          
                while (currentID >= parseNumber)
                    currentID /= parseNumber;

                //if is in still same range, add the row the new file
                if (currentID == firstNumber)
                {
                    ++rowsCurrent;
                    for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                    {
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowsCurrent, col] = xlRange.Cells[row, col].Value;

                    }

                }
                //new ID range, close the file, create a new one
                else
                {
                    //save current, reinitalise
                    newOne.SaveAs(folderPath + "\\excel" + firstNumber + ".xlsx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                              false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                           Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    rowsCurrent = 1;
                    firstNumber++;
                    row--;


                    //delete data
                    Range maxRange = xlWorkSheet.Cells;
                    Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1:A300", Type.Missing);
                    range.EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft);

                    //write header
                    for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                    {
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, col] = xlRange.Cells[1, col].Value2;
                    }


                }

            }

            xlWorkbook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            newOne.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            MessageBox.Show("parse done");
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: Not so sure what "content is overriden" might mean.  But there is a clear flaw in the code, it is not calling SaveAs() often enough.  One extra one is needed to save the last set of IDs.

Comment: i mean i only have saved the 0, 1, 2, 3, and 5. 4 is missing

Comment: That's what I understood.  You overwrote the 4 data when you started creating 5.  And never called SaveAs so when you called Close it got saved to disk.  Wiping out 4 on the disk.  Focus on making it work first with 1 set of IDs, 2 sets of IDs next, easier to debug.